# Add option to product in the cart progrmatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2

```
<?php
namespace Neologix\Bopis\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class SetAdditionalOptions implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,CheckoutSession  $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $infoDataObject = $observer->getEvent()->getInfo()->toArray();
        $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();

        foreach ($infoDataObject as $itemId => $itemInfo) {

           $item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
           $product = $item->getProduct();
           **// able to load product but after this code is not working for adding options to the product**
           $additionalOptions = array(
                array(
                    'code'  => 'my_code',
                    'label' => 'This text is displayed through additional options2',
                    'value' => 'ID is '
                )
            );
             $product->addOption(
                array(
                     'code'  => 'additional_options',
                     'value' => serialize($additionalOptions),
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: so what issue you are facing ?? can you describe ?

Comment: When the user is on cart page, I am adding custom options to the product on the click of update cart link but not able to add the option to the product with the above code. I am able to the product

Comment: can you give me event name ??

Comment: Yes , Event name is :- checkout_cart_update_items_after

Comment: I am able to load product on the click of update cart button with the help of the above observer code. But not able to set or add custom options to the product programatically here.

Comment: Here is the link to screen shot what i am talking about. Link :- prntscr.com/g3b90a

Answer (score 0):

try below event for your task

```
checkout_cart_update_items_before
```

because right now when you adding a product option but the quote is already updated so if you are setting up the custom option they are not getting saved

So use `before` event instead of `after`

you can see more info in this class

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.13/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Cart.php

Comment: This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try his code. It will work

```
       $additionalOptions[] = [
                'label' => 'This text is displayed through additional options2',
                'value' => 'ID is '
            ];

        if(count($additionalOptions) > 0){
            $item->addOption(array(
                'code' => 'additional_options',
                'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
            ));
        }
```